# Connect variables of the program with a function

Tags: python

My program has to take an integer N from the user (e.g. 5), creates a list of N integer random numbers from 1 up to 20 (e.g. [1,15,12,19,5]) and with the use of a function, calculates the average and the standard deviation of these numbers. My program so far is:

```
import random
import math

def stats(calculation):
    '''
    [9,20,15,9,11,19,2,4,16,8] -> MO = 11.30, SD = 6.07
    '''

    L=[]
    total = 0
    mathsum = 0

    for i in range(0,N,1):
        x=random.randint(1,20)
        L.append(x)

    for num in L:
        total += num

    MO = (total)/N

    for i in range(0,N,1):
        mathsum +=(L[i]-MO)**2

    sd = math.sqrt((1/(N-1))*mathsum)
    return N, L, '{:2.2f}'.format(MO), '{:2.2f}'.format(sd)

N=int(input('Give integer: '))
results = stats(N)
print('Number of integers: ', N)
print('List: ',L)
print('Average: ', MO, end='\t')
print('Standard deviation: ', sd)
```

It shows only the number of the List, but after that it gives error and cannot print the other three elements (L, MO, sd).

What is the problem?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: NameError: name 'L' is not defined. But if i erase the second print it shows the same message for MO and so on. Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `return` statement that you were assigning to `results` but not unpacking. Take a look at the following:

```
import random
import math

def stats(size):
    '''
    [9,20,15,9,11,19,2,4,16,8] -> MO = 11.30, SD = 6.07
    '''

    L=[random.randint(1,20) for _ in range(size)]
    total = sum(L)
    MO = total / size
    mathsum = sum((x-MO)**2 for x in L)
    sd = math.sqrt((1/(size-1))*mathsum)
    return L, '{:2.2f}'.format(MO), '{:2.2f}'.format(sd)

N=int(input('Give integer: '))
results = stats(N)
print('Number of integers: ', N)
print('List: ', results[0])
print('Average: ', results[1], end='\t')
print('Standard deviation: ', results[2])
```

Note that variables defined inside functions cannot be accessed by the outside scope. The reverse is possible but not recommended (`globals` used in functions). Since you are returning more that 1 values, the `results` become a `tuple` that you can index to get your stuff.

---

The mistakes aside, the logic of your code was sound but too verbose. Python allows you to write shorter, neater code.

Answer (score 0):

There are some design issues with your code which lead to te error you are getting.

1. Your function accepts an argument (`calculation`) but doesn't do anything with it. Instead it relies on `N` being a global variable. This is usually considered a bad design.
2. Your function returns a tuple but your calling code doesn't do anything with it. Instead it tries to access local variables that were created inside the function which causes the `NameError`.

As a fix, I suggest passing the information correctly to the function, and the function should return a dictionary instead of a tuple (which will allow clearer access to the returned values rather than remembering indexes).

```
def stats(n):
    '''
    [9,20,15,9,11,19,2,4,16,8] -> MO = 11.30, SD = 6.07
    '''

    L = []
    total = 0
    mathsum = 0

    for i in range(0, n, 1):
        x = random.randint(1, 20)
        L.append(x)

    for num in L:
        total += num

    MO = total / n

    for i in range(0, n):
        mathsum += (L[i] - MO) ** 2

    sd = math.sqrt((1 / (n - 1)) * mathsum)
    return {'n': n,
            'numbers': L,
            'average': '{:2.2f}'.format(MO),
            'sd': '{:2.2f}'.format(sd)}


n = int(input('Give integer: '))
results = stats(n)
print('Number of integers: ', results['n'])
print('List: ', results['numbers'])
print('Average: ', results['average'], end='\t')
print('Standard deviation: ', results['sd'])
```

Comment: So what can i do?

Comment: @Giannis See my answer